# Change structure of object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Been trying to change the structure of the following object for a while:

```
"Obj":{"0":"value1","1":"value2"}
```

Here's how I want to look. Like a simple array:

```
"Obj": ["value1","value2"]
```

Is there a simple way to do this? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Loop through the dictionary and add every value to an array. Seems pretty straightforward. I'd give you a write up but I'm not familiar with javascript so maybe there's something I'm missing.

Comment: `Object.values({"0":"value1","1":"value2"})`

Comment: @Andreas And for non-ES2017, `Object.keys(obj).map(function (key) { return obj[key]; })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Object.values.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) is the documentation. It returns an array of all the values of the object exactly how you want it.

```
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you also want to store keys:

```
o = {"Obj":{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}};

var newArray = [];

for(let i in o.Obj){
    newArray[i] = o.Obj[i];
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the structure as:

```
var obj = {"Obj":{"0":"value1","1":"value2"}};
```

To get the structure as you want you can do this:

```
obj["Obj"] = Object.values(obj["Obj"]);
```

The result will be:

```
obj = {"Obj" : ["value1", "value2"]};
```